# Strange occurence when passing values to bundle

Tags: android, opengl-es, arraylist, save, restore

I am using onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState to keep hold of my level data once my game is put in the background. It all seems to work fine but I have come across a consistent problem when you lock the phone using the power button. Instead of just calling save I also get a call to restore at the same time and then another call to save, then when I unlock my phone again I get another call to save and finally another call to restore. I have checked my values using Log tags and the first time my ArrayList gets returned as empty is after the second call to save after I lock my phone. Here is my stack trace:

```
//Locks Phone
10-23 08:34:03.797: DEBUG/input(6535): saveLevel[001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 000, 000, 000, 000, 001, 000, 001, 001, 001, 001, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 000, 000, 000, 001, 000, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000]
10-23 08:34:04.813: DEBUG/input(6535): RestoredLevel[001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 000, 000, 000, 000, 001, 000, 001, 001, 001, 001, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 000, 000, 000, 001, 000, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000, 000]
10-23 08:34:05.602: DEBUG/input(6535): saveLevel[]

//Unlocks Phone
10-23 08:34:14.656: DEBUG/input(6535): saveLevel[]
10-23 08:34:14.836: DEBUG/input(6535): RestoredLevel[]
```

The same thing doesn't occur when I exit the app by other means.

Here are my onSave and OnRestore methods:

```
 @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    levelDat = CSVReader.getleveldat(); //CSVReader is the class that creates the    ArrayList 
    outState.putStringArrayList("LEVELDATA", levelDat);
    Log.d(TAG, "saveLevel" + String.valueOf(levelDat));
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    levelDat = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("LEVELDATA");
    MRenderer.recoverLevel(); // just a method to force update my level data in my renderer.
    Log.d(TAG, "RestoredLevel" + String.valueOf(levelDat));
}
```

Is there a way to stop this from happening, if not could I have some tips to help me get my code to recognise the missing data and re-read the CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this post (http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/activity-lifecycle-explained-in-details/) there is a sample project which demostrates via logcat lifecycle events and when and which method is called. Long story short: you need to restore your state in `onCreate()`, not in `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Here is a sample of the log , when phone is locked:

```
10-23 10:50:20.847: I/TEST(913): A onSaveInstanceState
10-23 10:50:20.847: I/TEST(913): A onPause
10-23 10:50:20.847: I/TEST(913): A onStop
10-23 10:50:20.847: I/TEST(913): A onDestroy | isFinishing: false
10-23 10:50:20.859: I/TEST(913): A onCreate
10-23 10:50:20.859: I/TEST(913): A onStart
10-23 10:50:20.859: I/TEST(913): A onRestoreInstanceState
10-23 10:50:20.863: I/TEST(913): A onResume
10-23 10:50:21.210: I/TEST(913): A onSaveInstanceState
10-23 10:50:21.210: I/TEST(913): A onPause
```

As you can see, after invoking `onSaveInstanceState()` your activity is killed, then created again and because you miss to recover your state in `onCreate()` your ArrayList is empty.

Generally speaking `onRestoreInstanceState()` is used in special cases when some fancy / strange UI needs non-standard recovery of its state.

Comment: Is it possible to just put the `levelDat = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("LEVELDATA");` line from my restore method straight into onCreate?

Comment: Oh and is onDestroy called immediately after the phone is locked or after a period of time.

Comment: Yes, you can just move `levelDat = ...` to onCreate().

Comment: At least pn my phone (Galaxy S), `onDestroy()` is called immediately after locking.

Comment: If I haven't implemented onDestroy will it not get called? It doesn't sound very likely. I'm running on 2.2 atm btw.

Comment: Sorry, I did not quite understand your last comment about `onDestroy()`

Comment: I mean does onDestroy still get called if I don't override it in my code?

Comment: yep, "default" onDestroy() will get called, but that is not a problem. btw, if answers above both mine or goto10's are useful to you you should +1 them and/or accept them.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a shot in the dark, but the second save may be failing to find the data because it's been called too quickly after restore. I would have guessed that these methods were running on the same thread, but I'd try synchronizing on the data object to see if it's actually a race condition.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    synchronized(levelDat) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        levelDat = CSVReader.getleveldat(); //CSVReader is the class that creates the    ArrayList 
        outState.putStringArrayList("LEVELDATA", levelDat);
        Log.d(TAG, "saveLevel" + String.valueOf(levelDat));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    synchonized(levelDat) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        levelDat = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("LEVELDATA");
        MRenderer.recoverLevel(); // just a method to force update my level data in my renderer.
        Log.d(TAG, "RestoredLevel" + String.valueOf(levelDat));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer man but I've already worked out a work around. All I had to do was make sure the ArrayList from CSVReader class was up to date on restore (because that's where the renderer gets the level data initially) and also make sure any variables related to the ArrayList were updated (eg: I had the size of the arrayList stored in a variable somewhere)